# Neo4j Cypher match doesn't find node that it should

Tags: neo4j

Having added nodes with properties "id" and "name"

```
CREATE (s:subsystem {id: 12, name:"InjectEolCurrentCellSOCs"})
CREATE (s:subsystem {id: 13, name:"InjectEolCellCapacities"})
CREATE (s:subsystem {id: 14, name:"InjectEolCellResistances"})
CREATE (s:subsystem {id: 15, name:"InjectEolCellSOCs"})
```

This command works/finds the node and returns the requested value:
[image: This command works/finds the node and returns the requested value]

```
match(n {id:13}) return (n.name);
```

But this command does not find a match:
[image: But this command does not find a match.]

```
match(n {name:"InjectEolCellCapacities"}) return (n);
```

Could this be related to the fact that "InjectEolCellCapacities" and "InjectEolCellResistances" have the same first 13 characters ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your first imag, you will see that you have saved the data "InjectEolCellCapacities " (there is a space at the end).

So if you want to match it, yu should use this query : `MATCH (n:subsystem { name:"InjectEolCellCapacities "}) RETURN n`

You can also search all `subsystem` node that have a name property that starts with `InjectEolCellCapacities` like this : `MATCH (n:subsystem) WHERE n.name STARTS WITH 'InjectEolCellCapacities'  RETURN n`

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. The actual way the nodes were created were from a simple .csv file with the load cvs command. The source file simply looks like this. id,name
1,StateOfBatteryWrp
2,StateOfBattery
3,StateOfBatteryInit
4,StateOfBatteryCalc
5,StateOfBatteryTerm
6,BlendLastCANSOCWithPackSOC
7,ProvideTableBasedData
8,CheckForModuleQandRStatus
9,CheckForPackLowSOCStatus
10,CheckForEOLBasedPackReplacement
11,CheckForPackDegradedState
12,InjectEolCurrentCellSOCs
13,InjectEolCellCapacities 
14,InjectEolCellResistances
15,InjectEolCellSOCs  -- Apparently, line feeds are difficult

Comment: But one would think that whitespace at the end of the line in the .csv file would not be picked up in the load CSV command as part of the string. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You can use `trim()` when saving the csv value to a property to avoid this.